# What is causing an assertion error in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am validating a cstring to check if it has an uppercase character and a digit and if it does the loops end. The validatePassword function of my code causes an assertion error. Username is the character array. Fail is a boolean array which is changed to 1 if the cstring does need meet the input validation requirement. The cstrings are being read in from a text file. U_SIZE is the size of the cstring.

The assertion error says: 
Expression: c > -1 && c < 255

```
int main()
{
run();
return 0;
}

void run()
{
fstream inFile;

const int U_SIZE = 20;
const int P_SIZE = 20;

const int F_SIZE = 9;

int x = 0;

char user[20];
user[19] = NULL;

char username[U_SIZE];
username[19] = NULL;

char password1[P_SIZE];
password1[19] = NULL;

char password2[P_SIZE];
password2[19] = NULL;

bool fail[F_SIZE] = { 0,  //fail[0]
                      0,  //fail[1]
                      0,  //fail[2]
                      0,  //fail[3]
                      0,  //fail[4]
                      0,  //fail[5]
                      0,  //fail[6]
                      0,  //fail[7]
                      0}; //fail[8]

inFile.open("user_data.txt", ios::in);
inFile >> x;
inFile.ignore();

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
 {
    loadData(user, username, password1, password2, inFile);
    validateUsername(username, U_SIZE, fail, F_SIZE);
    cout << " " << endl;
 }
}

void loadData(char user[], char username[], char password1[], char 
password2[], fstream &inFile)
{
inFile.getline(user, 20); //read user
inFile.getline(username, 20); //read username
inFile.getline(password1, 20);// read password 1
inFile.getline(password2, 20); // read password 2
}

void validateUsername(char username[], const int U_SIZE, bool fail[], int 
F_SIZE)
{
char c;
char cTwo;
if (strlen(username) >= 10)
{
    fail[0] = 0;
}
else
{
    fail[0] = 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < U_SIZE; i++)
{
    c = username[i];
    if (isupper(c) != 0)
    {
        fail[1] = 0;
        i = U_SIZE;
    }
    else
    {
        fail[1] = 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < U_SIZE; i++)
{
    cTwo = username[i];
    if (isdigit(cTwo) != 0)
    {
        fail[2] = 0;
        i = U_SIZE;
    }
    else
    {
        fail[2] = 1;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. We need to know what `username` and `c` is, and how `username` is initialized.

Comment: Why don't you post which line specifically? How do you initialize `username`? How did you declare it?

Comment: Also, instead of doing `i = U_SIZE`, why not use the `break` statement to end the loop?

Comment: Furthermore, [`std::isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) is not guaranteed to return `1` if the character is upper-case, only that it's non-zero.

Comment: Lastly, is there a reason you use C-style strings and not `std::string`?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `username` so we know what type it is.

Comment: I need to use cstring because its a requirement for the project.

Comment: Seeing the whole program, here are a couple of other things: While C-style strings are called "null terminated", that "null" is not the null *pointer* which the macro `NULL` is for. Use either plain integer `0` or the character `'\0'`. Not that you *need* to initialize the arrays, since the `getline` function will add it for you. You also don't need `c` and `cTwo`, you can just reuse `c` in the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you go outside of your strings, you don't check for the terminator or the end of the strings in your loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < U_SIZE; i++)
{
    c = username[i];
    ...
```

The length of the string in `username` is `strlen(username)`. Outside of that the contents of the array might not be initialized properly, and its contents is *indeterminate*. And using indeterminate values, even just reading them, is *undefined behavior* in C++.

Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(username); i++)
{
    c = username[i];
    ...
```

instead.